# How to modify the size of a modal popup and its field and labels

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application. I have the following view, which I am rendering inside a modal popup windows :-

```
@model SkillManagement.Models.Staff

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}
@if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) { Html.RenderPartial("_modalHeader"); }
<h2>Edit Staff</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.StaffID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.timestamp)


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" } })
                @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)*@
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PrimaryRole, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.PrimaryRole, new { @class = "form-control", rows = 10 })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PrimaryRole)
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" /> |  @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}



@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

And the script is:-

```
$(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {

        $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
            $('#myModal').modal({
                height: 1000,
                width: 1200,
                resizable: true,
                keyboard: true
            }, 'show');
            $('#myModalContent').removeData("validator");
            $('#myModalContent').removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#myModalContent');
            bindForm(this);
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Currently the result is some how not very pleasant because; the field labels are being displayed on two lines, the columns are somehow big + the modal popup need to adjust its width.The result is:-

[image]

Now I used the firebug tool which detect the following css for the columns:-

```
*:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.form-control[disabled], .form-control[readonly], fieldset[disabled] .form-control {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    opacity: 1;
}
button[disabled], html input[disabled] {
    cursor: default;
}
input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
    max-width: 280px;
}
.form-control {
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
    color: #555;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 34px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out 0s, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
    width: 100%;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #999999;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

And the following css for labels:-

```
*:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.form-horizontal .control-label {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 9px;
    text-align: left;
}

.col-md-2 {
    width: 16.6667%;
}
.col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
}
.col-xs-1, .col-sm-1, .col-md-1, .col-lg-1, .col-xs-2, .col-sm-2, .col-md-2, .col-lg-2, .col-xs-3, .col-sm-3, .col-md-3, .col-lg-3, .col-xs-4, .col-sm-4, .col-md-4, .col-lg-4, .col-xs-5, .col-sm-5, .col-md-5, .col-lg-5, .col-xs-6, .col-sm-6, .col-md-6, .col-lg-6, .col-xs-7, .col-sm-7, .col-md-7, .col-lg-7, .col-xs-8, .col-sm-8, .col-md-8, .col-lg-8, .col-xs-9, .col-sm-9, .col-md-9, .col-lg-9, .col-xs-10, .col-sm-10, .col-md-10, .col-lg-10, .col-xs-11, .col-sm-11, .col-md-11, .col-lg-11, .col-xs-12, .col-sm-12, .col-md-12, .col-lg-12 {
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
label {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    color: #555555;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
}
```

Can anyone advice how to improve the appearance?

Comment: Since this is entirely a CSS issue, use the web inspector to copy your rendered HTML out. Paste that into a site like jsbin or jsfiddle and remove everything not directly related to the problem. If you are still having issues at that point put the link to your distilled problem here and someone will answer it for you very quickly.

Comment: @Zaqx i tried changing the CSS setting but none helped me in have a more plesent out put ..